# Reading .txt file through shell script stops after 1st line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, while-loop, ifs

I want to create a shell that reads a text file.

The file, `users_test.txt`, looks like:

Headers - *Group : Team : User*

```
Group_A:Team_Red Team_Green:worker_1 worker_2 worker_2 worker_3
Group_B:Team_Blue Team_Black Team_Grey:worker_4 worker_2 worker_5 worker_6
```

I want to loop through the .txt file above which is colon separated. Here is my current solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
# set filename
FILENAME="users_test.txt"

# loop through file, each  line is divided into 3 fields separated by a colon (:) 
while IFS=':' read -r groups teams users
do 
    echo "group $groups has teams $teams and user $users"
    
    for team in $teams; do
        echo "hey: "$team
    done
    
    for group in $groups; do
        echo "hi: "$group
    done

    # Iterate the string variable using for loop
    for user in $users; do
        echo "hello: "$user
    done

done < "$FILENAME"
```

Why does it end after the first loop iteration?

**output:**

```
admin@computer:$ ./setup-test1.sh
group  has teams Team_Red Team_Green and user worker_1 worker_2 worker_2 worker_3
hey: Team_Red
hey: Team_Green
hi: Group_A
hello: worker_1
hello: worker_2
hello: worker_2
hello: worker_3
admin@computer5:$
```

It seems to work fine but it ends after the first line, as a result Group B isn't printed.

Can anyone tell my why the script only reads the first line  containing Group_A but not the second line with Group_B?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your output with the script and input you provided. Recheck your script/data, maybe you fixed something as you put together the question? The only typo I notice off-hand is `worker 5` instead of `worker_5`. :)

Comment: Make sure the file uses `\n` as the newline, not `\r`.

Comment: @Erwin What output do you get? I've just repasted the code producing that output to be sure.

Comment: Bit tricky to share that in a comment. BTW, another typo is that `echo "group $group has teams $teams and user $users"` should say `$groups` instead of `$group`

Comment: You can paste here and set it to expire immediately or an hour - https://pastebin.com/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WjZcBFFh

Comment: Much appreciated, that's the exact output I'm looking for so my code is sound. No idea why I'm not getting that, I guess its probably has something to do with the AWS environment I'm running in.

Comment: As @Barmar commented, there may be newline or whitespace issues. Compare with this `xxd` output, see if you have some difference that you did not expect: https://pastebin.com/k94Hef39

Comment: @Erwin Had a look and the only differences I'm seeing are at the very end where your `xxd` output has `0a` at the end where mine doesn't. Not sure why this is as I've copied the txt sample from here back into my .txt file but still cant replicated your `xxd` output - https://pastebin.com/qBp5LQmS

Comment: I had to struggle to _not_ get a newline at the end of my `users_test.txt` file but once I did, I was able to reproduce your behavior, so that seems to be the exact issue

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the script and text file provided.

Comment: @Erwin ok thanks,  I'm still confused as to how omitting the feed line character `0a` at the end of my `users_test.txt` equates to producing  newline issue. More importantly, how do I rectify it? Currently I do the following: openNotepad-`Group_A:Team_Red Team_Green:worker_1 worker_2 worker_2 worker_3`-enterKey-`Group_B:Team_Blue Team_Black Team_Grey:worker_4 worker_2 worker_5 worker_6`-save. What should I do to create the txt file which runs without error, excuse my ignorance but I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: **Are you running on Windows** using one of the Unix-on-Windows environments like WSL, cygwin/mingw/git4win, gnuwin32, etc? Or are you creating the file on Windows and copying to Unix? While _Unix_ (including its shells) has a rule about ending the last line of a textfile with LF, _Windows_ does not and Windows programs like e.g. notepad will very easily create a file with no CRLF on the last line, and converting the actually-present CRLFs with dos2unix of tr or sed or similar doesn't change this.

Comment: Running in a unix environment, I was creating the text files through jupyter notebook which I suspect was the cause of my issues. Appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777230/reading-txt-file-through-shell-script-stops-after-1st-line/72779286#comment128548920_72777230) that your file doesn't end in a linefeed, `0a`:

```
$ printf 'foo\n' | xxd
00000000: 666f 6f0a                                foo.

$ printf 'foo' | xxd
00000000: 666f 6f                                  foo
```

here's the difference when trying to read such a file:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do echo "line=$line"; done < <(printf 'foo\n')
line=foo

$ while IFS= read -r line; do echo "line=$line"; done < <(printf 'foo')
$
```

A file that doesn't have a linefeed at the end is not a valid text file and so trying to read it with any text processing tool (e.g. [read](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/read.html) - note "The standard input shall be a text file.") is undefined behavior. It's not worth wasting time on what any tool does with such a file and why, just don't create files like that if you want to do any further text processing on them. If your editor creates files without terminating linefeeds then get a new editor, e.g. `vi`.